# Set gridSize (number of threads) dynamically in Spring Batch

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've a `spring batch` inside `spring boot` project which processes records present in an input file.

The number of records in the input file can vary anywhere between *1 to 1 million*.

I want to leverage multi-threading by partitioning the batch, as mentioned [here](http://walkingtechie.blogspot.in/2017/03/spring-batch-partition-example.html).

But I want the number of threads to be spawned should be decided on the basis of number of records in the input file.

Say, if records are <10,000 then only spawn 10 threads.
If they are >10,000 && <50,000 then spawn 20 threads & so on.

But if I'm not wrong, while *partitioning* the batch you have to provide the `gridSize` beforehand & implement `Partitioner.class` on the basis of that.

This is causing me a problem since value of gridSize should be present in `PartitionHandler bean`, like:

```
@Bean
  public PartitionHandler masterSlaveHandler() {
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    handler.setGridSize(****some dynamic value****);
    handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
    handler.setStep(slave());
    try {
      handler.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return handler;
  }
```

Since I don't know the value beforehand, my `@Configuration` class will not be build & will throw error.

So how can I set the gridSize dynamically?

*Please suggest. Thanks.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use lazy Scopes using `@StepScope` annotation to set Gride size

**Option 1: if you want to set grid size from stepExecutionContext**

```
@Bean
@StepScope
  public PartitionHandler masterSlaveHandler(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[gridSize]}") int gridSize) {
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    handler.setGridSize(gridSize);
    handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
    handler.setStep(slave());
    try {
      handler.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return handler;
  }
```

**Option 1: if you want to set grid size from job parameters**

```
@Bean
@StepScope
  public PartitionHandler masterSlaveHandler(@Value("#{jobParameters[gridSize]}") int gridSize) {
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    handler.setGridSize(gridSize);
    handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
    handler.setStep(slave());
    try {
      handler.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return handler;
  }
```